# Center text around a certain letter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, centering

I am trying to center a sentance in my Nav Bar (which uses bootstrap). The navbar so far looks like this:
[Centered Navbar title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwM6R.jpg)

What I would like to do is have the "|" centered, with the text around it next to it, instead of just having the sentence centered. This is quite hard to explain, but I hope you understand what I mean - the "|" is centered, with text to the left and right, instead of the whole sentance being centered, where the middle letter is in the middle. I want the "|" to be in the middle.
I have tried centering the "|" and floating the text on the left to the right and the text to the right to the left, but that just made the text go completely to the right instead of stopping before the "|".
Use the snippet to view the code, but please use "Full Page" so it works properly...

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://www.fontify.me/wf/da96db5dc1f0db255a8e71edaa0ace2d" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>
    <?php echo $album_nm; ?>
  </title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesnt work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
  <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------NAV BAR------------------------------------------------------ -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color: #1a1a1a;">
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="container" class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <div style="font-family: font71888;" class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
          <div style="display:inline-block; text-align: right;">
            CHLOE
          </div>
          <div style="display:inline-block; float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
            |
          </div>
          <div style="display:inline-block; text-align: left;">
            <?php echo $album_nm; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <a style="font-family: font71888;" class="navbar-brand page-scroll navbar-middle" href="#page-top"><br>CHLOE | <?php echo $album_nm; ?></a> -->
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="align: center; float: center; text-align: center;">
          <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
          <li class="hidden">
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#buy">Buy</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#story">My Story</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About Me</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#warchild">War Child</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#listen">Listen</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#thanks">Thanks</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

## Edit:

Thanks to [Andrei Gheorghiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891677/andrei-gheorghiu) for his answer, this worked for me and looked really nice! I have marked his answer as correct and it is the one with the most upvotes at the moment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
}
.navbar-brand > div{
  flex: 1 1 0;
  padding: 0 4px;
}
.navbar-brand > div:first-child,
.navbar-brand > div:last-child{
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
.navbar-brand > div:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
  <div>CHLOE</div>
  <div>|</div>
  <div>This is a long album name</div>
</div>
```

P.S.: Don't forget to [`autoprefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io) your CSS before deploying.
And stop using inline `style`! How are you going to wrap your declarations in a `@media` query if they're inlined?

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here.

Note: If you don't want to count mobile menu button when centering text, just remove overflow: hidden property from div that wraps the text

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://www.fontify.me/wf/da96db5dc1f0db255a8e71edaa0ace2d" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>
    <?php echo $album_nm; ?>
  </title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesnt work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
  <!-- -------------------------------------------------------------NAV BAR------------------------------------------------------ -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="background-color: #1a1a1a;">
    <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="container" class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <div style="font-family: font71888; float: none; overflow: hidden" class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
          <div style="display:block; text-align: right; width: 50%">
            CHLOE |
          </div>
          <div style="display:block; text-align: left; width: 50%" >
            <?php echo $album_nm; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <a style="font-family: font71888;" class="navbar-brand page-scroll navbar-middle" href="#page-top"><br>CHLOE | <?php echo $album_nm; ?></a> -->
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="align: center; float: center; text-align: center;">
          <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
          <li class="hidden">
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#buy">Buy</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#story">My Story</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About Me</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#warchild">War Child</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#listen">Listen</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#thanks">Thanks</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```